# How to average the channels of a jpeg image

Tags: arrays, r, image, average

I upload an image to r:

```
img=readJPEG("18105_552.jpg", native = FALSE)
```

and the I wrote a for loop to average the pixels:

```
options(digits=15)
m=matrix(data=NA, nrow=1, ncol=230400)
for(k in 1)
    for (i in (1: 480)){
          for (j in (1: 480)){
           m[k, ]<-((img[i,j,1]+img[i,j,2]+img[i,j,3])/3) 
            }}
```

However, my output is all ones. If I go in and manually try to get values, they are all .8 or .9 something, so I think r is rounding everything up to 1, but I can't seem to figure out how to stop it from doing so. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that img is an array structure or can be converted to one, this can be done without explicit loops using `rowMeans()`:

```
img <- array(runif(30,0.6,1),dim=c(10,10,3))
rowMeans(img,dims=2)
```

Or, to get it in one row:

```
matrix(rowMeans(img,dims=2),nrow=1)
```

This stores the numbers columnwise. Use `byrow=TRUE` to fill up row by row. Next to a correct result, you get a considerable speedup.

By the way, your problem is not rounding. The reason your solution doesn't work, is the following step:

```
m[k, ]<-((img[i,j,1]+img[i,j,2]+img[i,j,3])/3)
```

Here you calculate a single number, but assign that to the k'th row of the matrix `m`. R will recycle the single number, and fill the entire row with that single number. This one number will be the last one you calculated, and that might be the 1 in your case.

---

EDIT :

To do this for a set of pictures, store them in a list and use sapply to do the work for you:

Say:

```
img <- array(runif(30,0.6,1),dim=c(10,10,3))
img2 <- array(runif(30,0.6,1),dim=c(10,10,3))
```

Then make a list:

```
images <- list(img,img2)
names(images) <- c('img1','img2')
```

And :

```
m <- sapply(images,rowMeans,dims=2)
```

does what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to make a matrix so that it will store the average of each pixel in a column and then each column will be a different picture. Can you tell me how I can modify m[k, ]<-((img[i,j,1]+img[i,j,2]+img[i,j,3])/3) so that k is the image(1,2,...) and the column will list the average for each pixel?

Comment: Use the code I provided for you . The one line matrix(Rowmeans(... is doing exactly that for one image. There is no need for that loop. In fact, there's hardly ever need for a loop in R... Read this: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf  Circle 3.